# Iterate through filenames and remove extensions in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm an Erlang newbie.  I've tried to do my research on this, but as I am new to this language and confused by my code, I am posting here.

I want to iterate through the files in a directory and, for each file, run a command based on the filename (minus its extension).

As an example, this (untested) batch file should iterate through a folder of XML files, store the current filename in a variable (minus the file extension), and download a JPEG of the same name:

```
for %%a in (*.xml) do (

   set "current_filename=%%~na"

   wget -q -c -t 2 -0 "C:\Photos" "https://www.example.com/!current_filename!.jpg"

)
```

Here is my current Erlang module code:

```
-module(erlangtest1).

-include_lib("kernel/include/file.hrl").

-compile(export_all).

ListXmlFiles() -> lists:foldl(fun(Filename) ->
        FileInfo = file:read_file_info("C:/XML/" ++ Filename),
    end, 0, Filenames).
```

So far I am stuck on coding a function to retrieve filenames.  After I accomplish this I will try to run wget via os:cmd/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gather_filenames() ->
    [ begin
        "lmx." ++ NF = lists:reverse(FN),
        lists:reverse(NF)
      end || FN <- filelib:wildcard("*.xml", "C:/XML") ].
```

Or simpler but I don't know version when `filename:rootname/1` introduced

```
gather_filenames() ->
    [ filename:rootname(FN) || FN <- filelib:wildcard("*.xml", "C:/XML") ].
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **filelib:wildcard** function:

```
Filenames = filelib:wildcard("*.xml", "C:/XML")
```

Comment: I am trying to get this to work in my module, but I am getting this error: "syntax error before: Filenames"  Would you be able to show me what you mean in the context of my script so that I can understand?  Thanks!

Comment: I found the solution, which is wrap the command in a function like so:

gather_filenames() ->
    Filenames = filelib:wildcard("*.xml", "C:/XML"),
 Filenames.

Comment: @grgoelyk the variable is not needed in your function. This will do: gather_filenames() -> filelib:wildcard("*.xml", "C:/XML").

Comment: I see.  That simplifies my code.  However, I need to remove the file extensions from the list as well.